# Update Query using Temporary Table is taking a lot of time in Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, join, updates, temp-tables

I have a Main Table named REF_SERVICE_OFFERING where-in I already have 3 Million+ data. Now, I wanted to update the 3M records in Java based on some specific condition.

We decided to create a temporary table (where-in the records within will be used to Update the Main Table) and using the below query to Update the Main Table. The temporary table will hold more than 200k records :

```
UPDATE REF_SERVICE_OFFERING SET 
    PART_PRICE_BILL_TYPE= TEMP.PART_PRICE_BILL_TYPE,
    part_price_unit_type=TEMP.part_price_unit_type,
    part_price_allowed_units=TEMP.part_price_allowed_units,
    part_price_discount=TEMP.part_price_discount,
    part_price_source_id=TEMP.part_price_source_id
FROM REF_SERVICE_OFFERING RSO JOIN ref_offer_temp1 TEMP
ON  TEMP.RECORD_NUM =  RSO.RECORD_NUM 
AND TEMP.SO_NAME = RSO.SO_NAME 
AND TEMP.SERVICE_CASE_TYPE = RSO.SERVICE_CASE_TYPE
AND TEMP.WORK_ORDER_TYPE = RSO.WORK_ORDER_TYPE
WHERE (RSO.PART_PRICE_BILL_TYPE IS NOT NULL OR TRIM(RSO.PART_PRICE_BILL_TYPE) NOT LIKE '')
AND (RSO.PART_PRICE_EXCP_SOURCE_ID IS NOT NULL OR TRIM(RSO.PART_PRICE_EXCP_SOURCE_ID) NOT LIKE '')
```

Our database is Postgres 9.6.  But this update is taking a lot of time and never edning. We also tried dumping only 10k records in the temporary table which will be used to update 4L records.

We tried doing EXPLAIN command and couldnt figure out the reason why.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: We can't help you here, you need to have your DBA monitor the query to see what is taking the time.  There's a lot that could be wrong, including missing or out-of-date indexes.  The use of `NOT LIKE ''` looks really suspicious to me.  Again, only your DBA can provide this type of support.  Asking random strangers on the Internet, who have zero visibility into your database, is not likely to result in useful information.  Talk to your DBA.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer will depend on database characteristics, configuration and dynamic conditions to which SO users have no access.

Comment: ok thanks for the info. But i just wanted to check, if for updating such records, will this be a good approach ? As in dumping to temporary tables, creating index on top of the join clauses ? I have tried in Java using Prepared statement and doing a bulk update. But thats taking a lot of time. Hence went with this approach.

Comment: In principle if you do it right this is the correct approach.  I designed a similar system about 4 years ago and we achieved about a 10-to-1 performance improvement over the previous Java based system.

Comment: In my first comment, where I typed _"including missing or out-of-date indexes"_ I meant to say "missing indexes or out-of-date statistics".

Comment: Got it thanks @JimGarrison

Comment: `WHERE (RSO.PART_PRICE_BILL_TYPE IS NOT NULL OR TRIM(RSO.PART_PRICE_BILL_TYPE) NOT LIKE '')` Maybe you want **AND** here?

Comment: @joop, thx.. missed that too.. but i removed the whole OR clause, still the same .. never ending .. even when i try to update 3 records out of 3Million based on this.. its taking 5 minutes to update